# I just computed an DFT and FFT of a sinc function, but when I visualise them the results are strangely different? what am I missing

Tags: image-processing, discrete-signals, filter-design, lowpass-filter

The idea here is to improve a *Sinc* function by manipulating its Fourier transform.

As you can see, the *tophat* has ripples in the bands of interest and I want to eliminate them by smoothing them with a window or some filtering method, then take the DFT of the smoothed *tophat* to get the *Sinc*.

I want to compare the *Sinc* obtained from the smoothed *tophat* with the actual *Sinc* used to get the rippled *tophat*.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def fft(p):
  return np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft(np.fft.fftshift(p)))

##define discrete Fourier transform
def DFT(x):
    N = x.size
    #Create vector to store result in
    X = np.zeros(N, dtype=complex)
    for k in range(N):
        for n in range(N):
            X[k] += np.exp(-1j * 2.0* np.pi* k * n / N) * x[n]
    return X
x = np.array([-2.81131875e-02, -3.96997713e-02, -4.21368144e-02, -3.44452846e-02,
 -1.80464821e-02,  3.47617152e-03  ,2.51429695e-02,  4.17113849e-02,
  4.89232237e-02,  4.45735920e-02,  2.91392108e-02,  5.79606030e-03
, -2.02066174e-02, -4.26991128e-02, -5.60228061e-02, -5.64157843e-02,
 -4.30215932e-02, -1.82621467e-02 , 1.25480044e-02,  4.22981416e-02,
  6.36705197e-02,  7.08779634e-02,  6.11503378e-02,  3.56057506e-02,
 -7.36946338e-04, -3.98641156e-02, -7.24435298e-02, -8.99361403e-02,
 -8.66871186e-02, -6.15139083e-02, -1.83898004e-02,  3.40030403e-02,
  8.38410834e-02,  1.18587835e-01,  1.27818064e-01,  1.05851694e-01,
  5.36133160e-02, -2.07428262e-02, -1.02672849e-01, -1.73486957e-01,
 -2.13645119e-01, -2.06513036e-01, -1.41864949e-01, -1.84298219e-02,
  1.55066260e-01,  3.60639086e-01,  5.73509978e-01,  7.65904176e-01,
  9.11528887e-01,  9.89928563e-01,  9.89928563e-01,  9.11530481e-01,
  7.65911712e-01,  5.73528030e-01,  3.60669975e-01,  1.55108326e-01,
 -1.83838723e-02, -1.41826535e-01, -2.06494808e-01, -2.13657425e-01,
 -1.73533710e-01, -1.02749119e-01, -2.08345369e-02 , 5.35272126e-02,
  1.05793985e-01,  1.27807692e-01 , 1.18633975e-01,  8.39393878e-02,
  3.41351502e-02, -1.82532023e-02, -6.14064529e-02, -8.66385973e-02,
 -8.99643861e-02, -7.25486656e-02, -4.00269498e-02, -9.22081286e-04,
  3.54422496e-02,  6.10504637e-02,  7.08711442e-02,  6.37651928e-02,
  4.24781826e-02,  1.27749970e-02, -1.80408041e-02 ,-4.28604510e-02,
 -5.63580073e-02, -5.60886911e-02, -4.28797388e-02, -2.04643427e-02
 , 5.51990784e-03,  2.89109493e-02,  4.44513443e-02,  4.89421251e-02,
  4.18738004e-02,  2.54163255e-02,  3.79921602e-03, -1.77499417e-02,
 -3.42484465e-02 ,-4.20918559e-02, -3.98241253e-02, -2.83838352e-02])
def sinc(x):
        xu =  np.sin(x)/x
        xu[x==0] = 1
        return xu
xx = sinc(x)
dft = DFT(xx)
plt.plot(xx)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(dft/np.max(dft),label='DFT')
plt.plot(fft(xx)/np.max(fft(xx)),label='FFT')
```

where `xx` is some 1D *Sinc* function.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SE.SP!  Please include all code that is required to run. This code is missing import statements, and many of the variables and functions are redefined or referred to differently in different places (e.g. `sinc` vs `sinc0` or `x` vs `x0`.  Ping me once you've edited your question with these additions and I'll reopen it.

Comment: @PeterK. I have edited it.

Comment: @PeterK. Oh I see, in my fft I used the shifting properly, so how can I use it in DFT? well implementing it on python?

Comment: What is that `return np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fftn(np.fft.fftshift(p)))` at the top of the code? Looks like the last line of a function. Is this actually used in your code? Also please include `import` statements, they are part of complete code and are needed to run the example.

Comment: @CrisLuengo just edited.

Comment: @visco Please clear your cache and try running what you've change the code to. I'm still getting an error `File "<ipython-input-6-756de60fa167>", line 16
    -1.80464821e-02  3.47617152e-03  2.51429695e-02  4.17113849e-02
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. The numbers you've put in need to be comma separated in Python.

Comment: Your function `DFT()` is comparable to `np.fft.fft()`. If you remove all the `fftshift` calls, you should see the same results. Or you can add those same `fftshift` calls where you call `DFT()`: `np.fft.fftshift(DFT(np.fft.fftshift(p)))`.

Comment: Also, I still don't see `t1` defined anywhere.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I suspect the DFT output is only giving the real component, which accounts for the oscillations.

Comment: is there a way to smooth those ripples in the stop and pass band? then fourier transform back the smoothed top hat to get a sinc ?

Comment: @PeterK. everything fixed

Comment: @CrisLuengo it is still correct to shift DFT using fft?

Comment: The FFT is an efficient algorithm to compute the DFT, there should be no difference at all between the two. Not sure why you would worry about using `fftshift` to shift data, all it does is reorder numbers in an array.

Comment: @PeterK. The DFT produces a complex result, but `plt.plot()` only shows the real component, not the magnitude. So yes, that is the source of the large oscillations.

Comment: @PeterK, is it common to allow questions that are simply code dumps?

Comment: This questions would really benefit from a) describe what you are trying to do, b) describe how you current results are different from what you expect, c) put some comments in your code to describe what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Gillespie Ya. Probably not.

Comment: OP: Please address Hilmar's concerns.

Comment: @Hilmar alright. thanks for feedback

Comment: @Hilmar please see my new edits

Comment: @PeterK. please see my new edits

Comment: @CrisLuengo please see my new edits